# Javascript regex - Split string with words separated from spaces, commas and parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split the following string using regex in a way that every word, parenthesis, commas and spaces would be separated into string. I tried many times but can't find the right pattern.

```
var string = "WHEAT flour (49%) (with calcium, iron, niacin, thiamin), butter (MILK), pasteurised EGG, water, MILK, sugar, fresh yeast, salt, powdered pasteurised EGG"

var string = ["WHEAT"," ","flour"," ","(", "49%",")"," ","("," ",")" ......]
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this?

Thanks a lot for your help,
Nico

Comment: Is second line your expected output? and please show us one of those many tries you have made.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your own desired output what you really need is this:

```
([\s,()])
```

JS code:

```js
var string = "WHEAT flour (49%) (with calcium, iron, niacin, thiamin), butter (MILK), pasteurised EGG, water, MILK, sugar, fresh yeast, salt, powdered pasteurised EGG";
console.log(string.split(/([\s,()])/));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your intentions right but I would say you could use this simple regex:

```js
var string = "WHEAT flour (49%) (with calcium, iron, niacin, thiamin), butter (MILK), pasteurised EGG, water, MILK, sugar, fresh yeast, salt, powdered pasteurised EGG"

var array = string.split(/([\s,()])/);
console.log(array)
```

Here you can have a look at the regex expression: https://regex101.com/r/1yYCSN/1

**Regex output**: `var string = ["WHEAT"," ","flour"," ","(", "49%",")"," ","("," ",")" ...]`

**You expected output**: `var string = ["WHEAT"," ","flour"," ","(", "49%",")"," ","("," ",")" ......]`

Hope I could help.

Comment: OP doesn't want to split `49%` to `49` and `%`

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you split on `.`, it's a nonsense!